# Create a widget not reliant on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my code cleaner, and for this, I really like `JQuery widgets.`

Today, I would like to create a widget not related to a Dom Element :

```
$.widget('ui.resaWidget', {
    options : {
        viewer : null
    }...
});
```

The only way I've found to call this widget is:

```
$(aDomElement).resaWidget();
```

Is there a way to call my widget in a way like:

```
$.resaWidget()  ?
```

Because in fact, my widget is for the whole page generation, and not only for a single DOM element.

By the way, `$('body').resaWidget()` doesn't appear to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of creating jQuery plugins.

The most common one is to add a function to `jQuery.fn` (which is actually the same as `jQuery.prototype`):

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.foo = function (/* function parameters */) {
        this.each(doStuff);
        return this; //makes the function chainable
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This method is used to add functions callable on `jQuery` instances. I.E.:

```
$(selector).foo();
```

jQuery UI's widget factory is a shorthand means of extending `jQuery.fn`.

---

The other common means of extending jQuery is to add a function to `jQuery` itself:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.foo = function (/* function parameters */) {
        doStuff();
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This method is used to add statically callable functions from `jQuery`. I.E.:

```
$.foo();
```

jQuery UI's widget factory can't (currently as of 1.8) create these static functions. The main reason to use the widget factory is for the context preservation. If you have a static function without context (no `$()` needed), then you simply need to write your own functionality in the function.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
With this solution, I lose all the structure of the widget factory, I can't use "_" for private members and nothing for public ones. 

Is there a way to use both advantages, or I need to code my own factory ?

Comment: every function is only accessible within the scope of its closure. Standard JavaScript practices don't disappear just because you're using jQuery. I personally don't see the need for a factory for staticly accessible functions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but as of jQuery UI 1.9, you can now create non-dom based widgets by setting the `defaultElement` property on the widget prototype to `null`.